# How to read an XML element into a variable with Azure Data Factory

Tags: xml, azure-data-factory

I am trying to read in data from an API with Azure Data Factory. First I need to call a log in method, which provides an XML response. I need to take an element from that XML and put it into my next API call to get the data that I need.

Currently I am using the Copy data tool to call the log in method and save the XML to blob storage. How do I now read an element of that XML into a variable?

If there is a better way of doing this then please advise, but I would still like to know how to read an XML element into a variable.

Edit: here is the XML being returned. I need to capture the SessionID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <DoLoginResponse xmlns="http://foo.bar">
            <DoLoginResult>
                <OperationStatus>true</OperationStatus>
                <StatusMessage />
                <SecurityProfile>
                    <User></User>
                    <Session>
                        <SessionId>d2cf6ea6-120f-4bff-a5d1-adad9063d9d2</SessionId>
                    </Session>
                    <IsFirstLogon>true</IsFirstLogon>
                    <IsSystemOwner>false</IsSystemOwner>
                </SecurityProfile>
            </DoLoginResult>
        </DoLoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you want to extract a part of the xml file into a string variable?

Comment: Can you show us some example data and which part you want to extract?

Comment: I don't think ADF supports processing XML inline like this. One idea would be to pass the XML payload to an Azure Function that parses it and returns it as JSON, which would be easily readable into a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution1:**

I ended up getting it done by using the Lookup activity sourcing an XML data set connected an HTTP linked service. The returned XML is output from the activity as a json object which is normally accessable with activity('GetSessionID').output.etc. However, some of the element names contain a colon (soap:Envelope and soap:Body) and Azure Data Factory gave me a "BadRequest" error when I put these in as dynamic content. To get around this I converted it to XML, to string, stripped out the colons, converted back to xml, then to json. From there I could access the property like normal. This is the dynamic content that gave me the session id:

`@json(xml(replace(string(xml(activity('GetSessionID').output.firstRow)), ':', ''))).Envelope.Body.DoLoginResponse.DoLoginResult.SecurityProfile.Session.SessionId`

---

**Solution2:**

I think it is ok to extract a part of the xml file into a string variable. My idea is to convert the xml file into a string, and dynamically extract the SessionId part according to the expression.

I created a simple test here:

1. I'm using Lookup activity to get the xml file, you should replace with your web activity. I declared 2 String variables `XMLString` and `SessionId`:
   [image]
2. In `Set variable1` activity, add dynamic content `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0])` to assign value to variable `XMLString`. If you are using Web activity, the content should be `@string(activity('<Web_Actvity_Name>').output)`.
   [image]
3. In `Set variable2` activity, add dynamic content `@substring(variables('XMLString'),add(indexof(variables('XMLString'),'SessionId'),12),sub(indexof(variables('XMLString'),'}'),add(lastindexof(variables('XMLString'),'SessionId'),13)))` to assign value to variable `SessionId`.
   [image]
   The value of `SessionId` is as follows:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting it done by using the Lookup activity sourcing an XML data set connected an HTTP linked service. The returned XML is output from the activity as a json object which is normally accessable with `activity('GetSessionID').output.etc`. However, some of the element names contain a colon (soap:Envelope and soap:Body) and Azure Data Factory gave me a "BadRequest" error when I put these in as dynamic content. To get around this I converted it to XML, to string, stripped out the colons, converted back to xml, then to json. From there I could access the property like normal. This is the dynamic content that gave me the session id: `@json(xml(replace(string(xml(activity('GetSessionID').output.firstRow)), ':', ''))).Envelope.Body.DoLoginResponse.DoLoginResult.SecurityProfile.Session.SessionId`

Comment: Hi @jazzabeanie Your solution is great. I added it to my answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try and force the API to return results in JSON format so it's easier to work with in different situations. This can be done generally by adding a header to the api call. Key = Accept, Value = application/json;odata=verbose

Comment: This should be a comment; rather than an actual answer.